# Jquery Replace content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the content of the #textoGrande div with an external file.

I intend to use each menu li to call the included div files, avoiding the page to be reloaded.
My javascript include is empty... I don't know how to get started...

**Here's the html structure**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='include/javascript.js'></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Opera</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="header">

            <h1 id="logo">
                <a href="#">Linux Logo</a>
            </h1>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="player"></div>

        </div>
    <div id="imagen"></div>
    <h2 id="textoGrande"><p>Opera ahora<br /> mas acojedor...</p>
    </h2><h3 id="textoPequeno"><p>En su nueva versión, Opera apuesta por un nuevo diseño y pestañas visuales, un motor más veloz que incrementa su velocidad en un 40% frente a su anterior versión y un mejor soporte de estándares.</p>

    </h3></div>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("li a").live("click", function(){
       $("#textoGrande").load($(this).attr('href')+' body');    
       return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's only loading itself # ... How do you make it work for an specific html?

Comment: If I do that, for example
`<li><a href="test.html">Home</a></li>`
The entire page loads, the javascript doesn't seem to make any effect.

Comment: Still not working, what am I doing wrong? Please check the live sample: http://gabrielmeono.com/working/

Comment: @Gabriel: Try to use new jQuery, not sure if it will work but try to change 1.5.1 to 1.7

Comment: I thought it was, but not quite, It's removing the old div, but it does load the new content...

Comment: @Gabriel because you're replacing only the title "Opera ahora
mas acojedor...". That's your choice

Comment: Sorry I meant that it is NOT loading the new content.

Comment: I made a new question with the javascript you suggested, and still the page does not load.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047012/jquery-click-function-not-loading-new-content

Comment: @Gabriel I didn't notice you're not receiving .main class within ajax called page. Try to change .main to `body`

Comment: Forget it was chrome all this time. Tested with firefox and IE and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li a").click(function() {
    $("#textoGrande").load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Comment: It contains a sintaxis error in line 3. And doesn't do anything, the page loads entirely.